Angular Proxy Configuration for SSL Websocket (WSS)
I'm trying to configure the Angular CLI Proxy to forward websockets calls. The endpoint on application side is under /stream/feed and therefore I have put the following configuration in the proxy.conf.json:
{
  "/service/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:17580",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/stream/*": {
    "target": "wss://localhost:17580",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "ws": true
  }
}

Unfortunately and very strangely, it works for websocket (ws://...) but not over SSL (wss://...), except with direct access:
 - Connecting to: ws://localhost:4200/stream/feed
 - Connection Established
 - Connection closed
 - Connecting to: wss://localhost:4200/stream/feed
 - Connection failed, see your browser's developer console for reason and error code.
 - Connection closed
 - Connecting to: wss://localhost:17580/stream/feed
 - Connection Established
 - Connection closed

In the proxy configuration, I even asked to go over WSS, I don't know why it works for WS but not WSS. Any idea ?
